# Excluding folders starting with a dot in google drive API query

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, flysystem-google-drive

I am using `Python` client for **google drive API**.

I want to enumerate folders that has a name that does not start with a dot ('.').

My naive query to find the folders looks like this:

```
query = f"""
    {root_folder_id}' in parents
    and mimeType = '{FOLDER_MIMETYPE}'
    and trashed = false
    and not name contains '.'
    """
```

The reason I used the `contains` operator here is because it is stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#operators) quote:

> The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a name term.
> For example, suppose you have a name of HelloWorld. A query of name
> contains 'Hello' returns a result, but a query of name contains
> 'World' doesn't.

My query does *not* work. It does not find any folders. If I remove the offending last part `and not name contains '.'` then it finds all folders, including those with a dot at the start of the name, so I have narrowed it down to this part.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

You can try this other approach to enumerate folders that have a name that does not start with a dot ('.').

Fetch all the folders from a parent folder and then filter the result using python [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get all folders that do not start with dot.

### Code

```
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

#Authentication
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Set the parent folder ID
parent_folder_id = PARENT_FOLDER_ID_HERE

# Retrieve all folders from the specified parent folder
query = f"'{parent_folder_id}' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false"
results = drive_service.files().list(q=query).execute()
folders = results.get('files', [])
# Filter folders based on the criteria (no "." in the name)
filtered_folders = [folder for folder in folders if '.' not in folder['name']]

# Print the names of the folders that match the criteria
for folder in filtered_folders:
    print(f"Folder Name: {folder['name']}")
```

> NOTE: We may differ on the authentication part of the code since I am using google Colaboratory on running this code

### Output:

[image]

### Parent Folder on Google Drive:

[image]

### References:

[List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

[Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22%271sTMxZyxKViCu6jX3Jfz6bLch3j6R-O0e%27%20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27%20and%20name%20contains%20%27%5C%22.%5C%22%27%22%7D)